# SQL Server 2005 Management finds no database, 2008 won't install

Tags: sql-server

In the past, I installed Visual Studio 2010. With that comes SQL Server.

Now I installed this:[Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express](https://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c243a5ae-4bd1-4e3d-94b8-5a0f62bf7796)

Now, upon starting, I get this screen: 
[image]

And it doesn't matter what Server name I enter, nothing works.

I've tried installing SQL Server 2008 Enterprise(I can get that via MSDNAA), but that fails totally, giving me this error:

> ### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Setup
>
> The following error has occurred:
>
> Unable to open Windows Installer file
>   'G:\x86\setup\sql_engine_core_inst_loc_msi\1033\sql_engine_core_inst_loc.msi'.
>
> Windows Installer error message: The
>   system cannot open the device or file
>   specified. .
>
> Click 'Retry' to retry the failed
>   action, or click 'Cancel' to cancel
>   this action and continue setup.
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=10.0.2531.0&EvtType=0xC24842DB
>
> ------------------------------ BUTTONS:
>
> ### &Retry Cancel

There is no help, I can click retry as much as I want, nothing changes. I went to the file itself, and Windows says I should check if it is a valid installer file.

And that's my story. I need to get this up and running, and it's all going against me. Can anyone help?

Comment: I completely revamped my answer

Answer (score 1):

Oops, I have the same problem [1]!
Though I did not investigate the issue 
(since I do not need now VS2010 or SQL Server Express)
You can find helpful the answer to my [2] which was reported helpful to resolve the problem by others.

I am afraid it should be reported as bug to MS Connect, though I do not have time and desire to invest time in investigation. Anyway, when MS teams cannot resolve something they close bugs "by design" or "not reproduced"

Since there is no channel to report bugs on SQL Server 2005 xxx (or VS2008), for which the reports are closed, it should be reported in VS2010 board.

Give link if you report, I shall upvote the bug and mark it as reproduced by one more.

### My related questions (having some solutions):

in asp.net "Visual Studio and Visual Web Developer Express " forum, frequently answered by MS teams

[1]
S2010RC setup installs unusable MSSQL2008 Express?
(the same problem as yours, unanswered)
http://forums.asp.net/t/1571173.aspx

[2]
MSSQL2008R2 (BIDS, i.e. VS2008) after VS2010?
(answered and solution is reported to be helpful to others)
http://forums.asp.net/t/1568816.aspx

[3]
to submit bug reports on BIDS 2008 R2 as VS2010 bugs?
http://forums.asp.net/t/1568807.aspx